# Adding UIView as a subview to a UIButton and bring it to front is not working properly

Tags: swift, xcode, uiview

I have a UIButton, the background color is white.

```
@IBOutlet weak var buttonNewPost: UIButton! {
    didSet {
        buttonNewPost.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.88, green:0.88, blue:0.88, alpha:1.0).cgColor
        buttonNewPost.layer.cornerRadius = 5
        buttonNewPost.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

I want to add an UIView to add a shadow to this rounded button:

```
    let buttonShadow = UIView()
    buttonShadow.frame.size.width = buttonNewPost.layer.bounds.width
    buttonShadow.frame.size.height = buttonNewPost.layer.bounds.height
    buttonShadow.backgroundColor = .clear
    buttonShadow.dropShadowEdged = true
    buttonShadow.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    buttonNewPost.addSubview(buttonShadow)
    buttonShadow.bringSubviewToFront(buttonNewPost)
```

The result is like this:

[image: y]

Why is the UIButton not in the front with the white background color? When I change the backgroundcolor of the UIButton to blue:

[image]

Why is it like that? I just want a white button with a shadow

Comment: What about this: `buttonNewPost.bringSubviewToFront(buttonShadow)` ?

Answer (score 0):

You can apply shadow directly to UIButton:-

```
@IBOutlet weak var Btn: UIButton! {
        didSet {
            Btn.layer.borderColor = UIColor(red:0.88, green:0.88, blue:0.88, alpha:1.0).cgColor
            Btn.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            Btn.backgroundColor = .white
        }
    }
```

Add below code to Viewdidload:-

```
Btn?.layer.borderColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
Btn?.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
Btn?.layer.cornerRadius = 20.0
Btn?.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
Btn?.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.red.cgColor
Btn?.layer.shadowRadius = 5.0
Btn?.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0.0, height: 0.0)
```

[After using this code you will get result like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vu0Mu.png)